# Using Django how can I get a set of records where the value used for filtering is to a many-to-many field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Assuming I have data that resembles:

```
id | value | m2m__created | m2m__value
---+-------+--------------+-----------
 1 | 10    | 2020-03-14   | 0
 1 | 10    | 2020-03-21   | 5
 2 | 20    | 2020-03-14   | 10
 3 | 30    | 2020-03-14   | 20
```

what I want after filtering is:

```
id | value | m2m__created | m2m__value
---+-------+--------------+-----------
 1 | 10    | 2020-03-21   | 5
 2 | 20    | 2020-03-14   | 10
 3 | 30    | 2020-03-14   | 20
```

I'm trying to use something like this:

```py
Foo.objects.filter(
    foo_m2m__created__lte=start_date,
).order_by(
    'id',
    '-foo_m2m__created',
).annotate(
    recently_created=Max('foo_m2m__created'),
).values(
    'id',
    'value',
    'foo_m2m__created',
    'foo_m2m__value',
)
```

unfortunately, what I get is this:

```
id | value | m2m__created | m2m__value
---+-------+--------------+-----------
 1 | 10    | 2020-03-14   | 0
 2 | 20    | 2020-03-14   | 10
 3 | 30    | 2020-03-14   | 20
```

I've tried adding another `.filter(foo_m2m__created=F('recently_created'))` following the annotation, but the same thing happens.

Comment: what are you trying to do with your filter? (the logic)

Comment: sorry but I don't understand the question. ultimately, I'm just trying to get a list of results as described

Comment: Can you explain your requirements in plain English? or What is the logic behind the conversion of *source table* to *required result table* ?

Comment: I have a table of items which have a value, for each item there can be one or more records of changes to that item where the date the change is made and the change are recorded. For a list of items I need to get the record of change that exists most recently before a start date that is provided. This will be run over potentially hundreds of items with potentially hundreds of historical records so I need to minimize the results for performance as much as possible and am trying to do that by keeping things in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by using something along these lines of:

```py
foo_max_set = Foo.objects.filter(
    foo_m2m__created__lte=start_date,
).values(
    'id',
    'foo_m2m__created',
).annotate(
    max_created=Max('foo_m2m__created')
).order_by('id')

q_statement = Q()
for item in foo_max_set:
    q_statement |= (Q(pk=item['id']) & Q(foo_m2m__created=item['max_created']))

foo_history = Foo.objects.filter(q_statement).distinct().values(
    'id',
    'value',
    'foo_m2m__value'
)
```

This gets what I need using two queries, which is the best that I've been able to achieve. I'd still be interested in seeing something that does it in one if there was a clever way.